# How do you use a binary search using only words and not numbers?

Tags: java, binary-search

I was asked to use **binary search** to **find** specific **words** in a file that we read.

The issue I do not understand is how to use a binary search when you are looking for **words and not numbers**.

Comment: How do you use it for numbers? What prevents you to do the same for words?

Comment: Here's a demo implementation a quick google search yield: [GitHub Gist: BinarySearch.java](https://gist.github.com/aviraldg/2195495). It's just the regular algorithm where comparisons like `<` are exchanged by `compareTo` in order to work for objects like `String`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary search operates on **sorted inputs**. You can define an [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) also on words, not only on values.

For example the [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). In Java this is even implemented as the **natural order** of `String`s. So you can do `"text1".compareTo("text2")` and it returns the order.

---

A small illustration of binary search:

[image: Binary search illustration]

As you see, the only thing to decide in the algorithm is the order between two objects. For example, from the image, `7 < 14` and `7 > 6`. As said, you can also do this for `String`s. Indeed for **everything** for which you **define an order**.

Actually many classes in Java (more than `150`) implement a **natural order**, they are listed under the interface `Comparable` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)), they all provide a `compareTo` method with a **meaningful order**.

Comment: Is there a way you could show me an example of how you would use a string with letters to search a text document? I'm still a bit confused about it!

Comment: Take your binary search algorithm for values, exchange it by `String`. The only thing left is exchanging comparisons by `<` or `>` with the `String#compareTo` method. If you show me your code I'll edit it for you and explain the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Think of looking up a word in the dictionary; this is an example of binary search.

For example, lets look up "eunoia":

1. You flip open the dictionary to approximately the "E" section but maybe you go a little too far and end up in the "M" section.
2. You flip about half way back and now you're in the "E" section (if you're lucky)
3. Move onto the next letter in the word and repeat.

This all works because the dictionary is **well-ordered**, we all agree that A is the 1st letter, B is the 2nd, etc. Another way to look at it is that the Alphabet is the same thing as the numbers [0 - 25] just with different names.

Comment: Is there a way you could show me an example of how you would use a string with letters to search a text document? I'm still a bit confused about it!

Comment: @noel Spot on!! Dictionary is the best example use-case

Answer (score 0):

Binary Search for **string** Implemented in C.

```
    char *lineptr[MAXLINE]  //Array of char pointers stores the address of string
    int binsrch(char srch[],int low,int high)
    {
       int mid;

       if(high>=low){
          mid=(low+high)/2;
          if(strcmp(srch,lineptr[mid])<0) //compare string stored in srch and lineptr[mid]
                return binsrch(srch,low,mid-1,count);
          else if(strncmp(srch,lineptr[mid],count)>0)
               return binsrch(srch,mid+1,high,count);                                                      
          else 
               return mid; // Found
       }
     return -1;  //Not found
  }
```